# Converting cli curl to php url

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface

I have problem with converting cli cURL to php cURL version.
I've tested such link from cli:

```
curl -H "X-API-KEY: key" -XPOST -v -H "Accept: application/json" http://sentione.com/api/statements/search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"topicId":id, "from": "2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 CET"}'
```

and it's working properly.

And that's my code.
I got no response.

```
 $headers = array(
        "Content-type: application/json",
        "X-API-KEY: key",
        "Accept: application/json"
);
$arr = array(
    "topicId" => id, 
    "from" => "2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 CET"
);
$url = "http://sentione.com/api/statements/search";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($arr));
$response = curl_exec($curl); 

print_r($response);
```

Of course I set correct api key and topic id.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think $curl = curl_init($url); and remove next line to it will help you

Comment: @SunilPachlangia you're not right. This syntax is correct too. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, see at my array declaration.
I used : instead of =>. I don't know why.
It's solved, thanks anyway! :)